# Setting user_session variable after Devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I had this working then came back to my app after a few months now it's broken.  I am sure it's a subtle change in a gem somewhere or I am missing something obvious.

In my application controller I have this:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

    user_session["company_id"] = current_user.default_company_id
    cookies[:login] = { :value => current_user.email, :expires => Time.now + 2.weeks}
    dashboard_path
  end
```

If I call `user_session["company_id"]` later it's `nil` (`current_user.default_company_id` works).

If I set `user_session["company_id"] = current_user.default_company_id` in the code just before where I call `user_session["company_id"]` to fetch the value it works.

Comment: why do you use `user_session` and not `session` ?

Comment: I saw that used in another example and just carried that over.  I even tried using session and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set company_id in a method calling before_filter in application controller as following

```
before_filter :set_company_id

def set_company_id
    session["company_id"] = session["company_id"] || current_user.default_company_id if current_user
end
```

Erase setting company_id in after_sign_in_path_for method

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    cookies[:login] = { :value => current_user.email, :expires => Time.now + 2.weeks}
    dashboard_path
end
```

Comment: Yes - that is correct but to clarify in my situation I want to set the session["company_id"] after login.  The user then can "switch" companies and the session["company_id"] gets changed.  In this case the current company id would always revert to the default.

Comment: I have edited the answer, before set company_id, you should check if any company_id is there it will not reset to default company id. wish you will get an idea from this.

Comment: That should work - the question that still nags at me is why does what I had originally not work?  I had it working like that before so I would still like to know what changed.